# Alternative to adding spaces in strings in NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-2.0

I am creating a server-client model and am forced to use .NET 2.0 as my framework due to the nature of my development environment on the client side.

Introduction aside, let's say I wanted the console to output a new connection was made from a certain ip address at a certain time. I would write:

```
Console.Writeline("New connection: " +
                  client.endpoint.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

I was wondering if there is an alternative to this line. Some of these lines are becoming very long and feels a bit untidy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the `Console.WriteLine()` [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc0cx9a5(v=vs.110).aspx). It doesn't save much, but perhaps it more naturally splits the statement into multiple lines, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine("New connection: {0} {1}", 
                  client.endpoint, 
                  DateTime.Now);
```

You can also explore the [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  You can configure the Trace options to always output the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c(v=vs.110).aspx%20DateTime) so you'd be able to skip that parameter.  Then, you can add a [ConsoleTraceListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx) to write those Trace messages to the Console.  Using this approach, you'd do something like:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("New connection: {0}", client.endpoint);
```

Comment: @ArkayCZ pretty much gave a similar answer in terms of the String.Format method, but you also mentioned the Trace class, which helped shorten my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.Format, which makes the string more readable. It does not exactly answer your question, but still. You use it like this:

```
String s = String.Format("New connection: {0} {1}.", client.endpoint.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

And with `Console.WriteLine`, you can just do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("New connection: {0} {1}.", client.endpoint.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending a lot of strings together, I suggest you to use `StringBuilder` class in the .Net Framework. This will improve performance.

For adding spaces, you can define a variable as `string separator = " ";` and use this to create the string.

After creating the string with the `StringBuilder`, you can write it to the console or do other things as per your need.

Comment: I will also look into this.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution could be creating helper method that will take unlimited parameters (Arguments) of type string and then using string.Join() method to combine and format the text before writing it to screen:

```
static void ConsoleLog(params string[] data)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", data));  
}
```

Then to use this method:

```
ConsoleLog("New connection:", client.endpoint.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Or to make it easier to read/edit:

```
ConsoleLog(
    "New connection:",
    client.endpoint.ToString(),
    DateTime.Now.ToString()
    );
```

Comment: An interesting solution but using the `Console.WriteLine` overload seems less cumbersome, since I won't have to create a new method to join the data as you have done with `ConsoleLog`.

Comment: I think this solution is actually less cumbersome, maybe it will be little slower than overload  (more computations and function call) but its easier to just add commas instead of adding {0} and format it and if there is a lot of strings to add you can accidentally skip number and get errors etc.